# FullCalendar 'basicWeek' header display

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm looking to find out if there is an option to change the way `basicView` for `fullcalendar.js` is displayed.  When I display my calendar in `basicView` I get something like this:

```
9/13 9/14 9/15 9/16 9/17...
```

when I would like it to display something like this:

```
13 14 15 16 17...    // No month, just days
```

I've looked through the [documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/) for about an hour and can't find anything to change this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `columnFormat` parameter:

```
columnFormat: 'ddd DD'
```

See http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/columnFormat/

You can even specify a format for each view:

```
 views: {
        basicWeek: { // name of the view
            columnFormat: 'ddd DD',
        }
    },
```